# Outputting UDP From Logstash

Tags: logstash

I have some  logs that I want to use logstash to collate . It will be the logstash agent as a shipper on the source servers going to a central logging server . I want to use UDP from the shipper to the central log so I can be totally isolated should the logger fail ( I dont want the 70 odd production servers affected in any way ) . The only way I can see of using udp for the transport is to output using  syslog format . Does anyone know of a way I can output UDP natively from logstash ? ( The docs hint at it but I must be missing something on the TCP side ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output UDP natively using the UDP output plugin

- http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.1/outputs/udp

By setting the codec field, you can choose whatever output format you like (e.g. JSON)

Comment: This may seem obvious once you know, but make sure you set the codec the same on both shipper and server side - took me a while to figure out while events weren't going across before I figured this out.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the typical approach would be to use something a bit more lightweight (rsyslog, or even Lumberjack) running on the remote machine, that is sending data to your central logstash server.

It sounds like you want logstash agents (forwarders) to be running on each server and sending the data to the broker. This blog [post](http://www.vmdoh.com/blog/centralizing-logs-lumberjack-logstash-and-elasticsearch) (also linked as an example below), gives a nice explanation of why they chose not to use logstash forwarders on their remote servers - they eat too much RAM

I use a setup where rsyslog sends UDP data to logstash directly. I've also used a setup where rsyslog was the receiving log server, and aggregated the logs into separate logfiles (based on server hostname) and then logstash read from those files.

For some example configs see the following:

- [Logstash with Lumberjack and ES](http://www.vmdoh.com/blog/centralizing-logs-lumberjack-logstash-and-elasticsearch)
- [Logstash with rsyslog and ES](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/entries/23163863-Installing-Logstash-Central-Server)

I suggest the rsyslog approach, as the chances that rsyslog is already running on your server is higher than Lumberjack. Also there is quite a bit more documentation on rsyslog than Lumberjack. Start off simple, and add more complexity later on, if you feel the need.