# Logstash shipper & server on the same box

Tags: syslog, logstash

I'm trying to setup a central logstash configuration. However I would like to be sending my logs through syslog-ng and not third party shippers. This means that my logstash server is accepting via syslog-ng all the logs from the agents.

I then need to install a logstash process that will be reading from /var/log/syslog-clients/* and grabbing all the log files that are sent to the central log server. These logs will then be sent to redis on the same VM.

In theory I need to also configure a second logstash process that will read from redis and start indexing the logs and send them to elasticsearch.

My question:

Do I have to use two different logstash processes (shipper & server) even if I am in the same box (I want one log server instance)? Is there any way to just have one logstash configuration and have the process read from syslog-ng ---> write to redis and also read from redis ---> output to elastic search ?

Diagram of my setup:

[client]-------syslog-ng---> [log server] ---syslog-ng <----logstash-shipper ---> redis <----logstash-server ----> elastic-search <--- kibana

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to use two different logstash processes (shipper & server) even if I am in the same box (I want one log server instance)?

Yes.

> Is there any way to just have one logstash configuration and have the process read from syslog-ng ---> write to redis and also read from redis ---> output to elastic search ?

Not that I have seen yet.

Why would you want this? I have a single machine and remote machine config and they work extremely reliably, with a small footprint. Maybe you could explain your reasoning a bit - I know I would be interested to hear about it.

Comment: do you really need to have different processes? what is the correction way to set this up? For only one day I managed to have one process ship and index to elastic. now its not working, maybe I need your approach!

Comment: Check another answer of mine [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318488/outputting-udp-from-logstash/16633017#16633017) that gives some examples for that approach. One direct [example](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/entries/23163863-Installing-Logstash-Central-Server)